# Question about Hausdorff spaces and their equivalences

Tags: general-topology

Definition: A topological space $X$ is called Hausdorff  space if for each $x_1,x_2 \in X$ (they are distinct) we can always find neighborhoods $U_1,U_2$ of $x_1,x_2$  such that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \varnothing $.

Is this definition equivalent to say that the following set

$$ \mathcal{D}  = \{ (x,x) : x \in X \}$$

is closed in $X \times X $ ??
 Im having difficulties seeing why this istrue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.